# Can you acquiretokesilently for PowerBI without Username and Password

Tags: azure, token, powerbi

After a day and a few hours of search on PowerBI and read samples of PowerBI webapp, i ran into a wall, what is the best way to change the underneath code

```
            var tokenCache = new TokenCache();
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, tokenCache);
            var token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri)).AccessToken;
```

to get the access token **Sliently** for power Bi rest API. I know there is a AcquireTokenSlientAsync but when i register my app as WebApp including the cliendID and clientSecret it gives me a 403 error.

Currently my web app is register on the dev powerbi as a NativeApp and getting the token on each request. But it has a pop up everytime.

Because i am using the access token to embed various reports on a web page, it would be great if someone can show me the light of how to acquire the token sliently without using UserName and password.

I have tried using `var token = authContext.AcquireTokenSlientAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential);`

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the initial app authentication using AAD? Are the reports your attempting to show user specific?

Comment: @JustLogic The initial app authentication is using the microsoft graph authentication retrieving claims, and then yes reports that i am trying to use are user specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you can do is use the "refresh" token that you get on the initial authentication. That initial token should include a refresh token, with the refresh token you can use the "AcquireTokenByRefreshToken" method and pass in the new resource (power bi api) you need an access token for.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new AdalTokenCache(claim.Value));

var refresh_token = authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().FirstOrDefault().RefreshToken;

ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

var resp = authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(refresh_token, credential, "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, just one question, the clientCredential (appKey) are we referring to PowerBI clientSecret after registered as webapp? Thanks

Comment: Also my initial authentication were using SessionTokenCache, therefore i suppose i will get the token from the session in the webapi and retrieve it...

Comment: Yes the client id and appkey(client secret) are the id's from the app that is registered with aad.

Comment: thank you for your answers, i did solve it in the end using refreshToken :)